# Tensorflow model.predict() produce NaNs for last few images in an array of image input

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow2.0, predict, inference

When loading a model and using it for inference, I feed in an array of images,
`image_tile_tensor` where the shape is `(total_tile, tile_height, tile_width, 3)`. `image_tile_tensor` is a numpy array.

I input this into my model for inference using the code below:

```
image_tile_tensor = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image_tile_tensor, tf.float32)
image_tile_prediction = model.predict(image_tile_tensor, verbose=1)
```

During inference, all the prediction come out nicely except for the last few image tile in `image_tile_tensor`. For example, if I have 112 total image tile for inference, the last 12 image tiles has prediction with all values equal to `NaN` while the first 100 image tile has the expected prediction value.

Any idea what the problem might be? I am abit lost and dont know where to start debug this at the moment. If it helps, the input `tile_height` and `tile_width` are `(192,192)` and training `batch size = 16`.

Comment: Will it be possible to provide minimal code snippet to investigate the issue.Thanks